# Using GraphQL values with React When They Might Be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, default-value, react-proptypes

It seems that when a value isn't found in a GraphQL query, it sets that field to `null` not `undefined` (See issue [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/731)).

> null is the undefined or None of GraphQL

Given that React won't use a default prop for a `null` value, what is the best way to handle the situation where GraphQL data is being passed into a React Component.

For example I have a `TagList` component into which I am passing the result of a GraphQL query. Although I have the following:

```
TagList.defaultProps = {
  tags: [],
}
```

If the query returns no tags, the value of `tags` will not be `undefined`, but `null`, so the default value isn't applied, and the component tries to render using `null` as the value of tags.

Obviously I can add a check at the top of the render method and set the value to `[]`, but it feels like there must be a better solution.

Comment: try using a ternary operator.
I am just a beginner so I am not sure whether I am right

Answer (score 2):

The GraphQL spec doesn't include a concept of an undefined value -- values are simply either null or non-null. In fact, when outlining the steps for resolving a field's value, it specifies undefined should be coerced into a null value:

> If result is null (or another internal value similar to null such as undefined or NaN), return null.

That said, off the top of my head, there's a few ways you could solve this:

1.) On the client side, create a small HOC that you can wrap your components in:

```
const UndefinedToNull = (Component) => (props) => {
  const newProps = props.map(p => p === null ? undefined : p)
  return <Component {...newProps}>
}
```

2.) If you're using Apollo as a client, you should be able to create a middleware link that converts null to undefined. Something like:

```
const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  return forward(response).map(result => {
    // transverse the result, mutating it as needed
    return result
  })
}
```

3.) On the server side, if you're using `apollo-server`, you can use the `formatResponse` configuration option to transverse the GraphQL response and convert nulls or undefined as needed. YMMV with other GraphQL middleware.